# dynamic dataset in stimulsof with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I use stimulsoft in asp.net mvc for reporting ...
I want to bind a dynamic datatable/dataset into my report , So I search for it and
There is my code
View:

```
@Html.StiMvcViewerFx(new StiMvcViewerFxOptions()
{
    ActionGetReportSnapshot = "GetReportSnapshot",
    Width = Unit.Percentage(100),
    Height = Unit.Pixel(700),
    Zoom = 100
})
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetReportSnapshot()
        {
            var report = new StiReport();
            //a blank file .mrt
            report.Load( Server.MapPath("~") + "Content/StimulReport/Data/Surveys/Report/Report.mrt" );
            var dt = new DataTable("Text");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            var dataSet = new DataSet("Demo");
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
            report.RegData(dataSet);
            return StiMvcViewerFxHelper.GetReportSnapshotResult(report);


        }
```

But the Report Just Show A Blank Page:
[image]

For windows application it's work correctly but in web it's not
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next code:

```
report.RegData(dataSet);
return StiMvcViewerFxHelper.GetReportSnapshotResult(this.Request, report);
```